# xamarin android aplication does not work with proxy

Tags: android, proxy, xamarin

I have a xamarin android app that uses a webservice.

It works fine in normal environment, but, if i try to use the app in a android that is conected to a proxy, then the app can't access the webservice, what's more, the proxy firewall is not reciving the petitions, as if the petition is not throw for the app.

Do I have to configurate the proxy in my app? if so, how?
Can it be another problem?
Does it have solution?

Comment: do you use any specific port in your app? It might be not supported by proxy. Proxy usually handles 80 and 443 ports.

Comment: No, i don't use any specific port.